# How to Disable Publishing And Distribution?

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication

I'm getting the following error while disabling publishing and distribution. Plz, tell me how to do disable publishing and distribution?

> SQL Server could not disable
>   publishing and distribution on
>   'server'.
>
> An exception occurred while executing
>   a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The Distributor has not been installed
>   correctly. Could not disable database
>   for publishing. Changed database
>   context to 'master'. (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 20029)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I executed the following query

sp_removedbreplication @dbname = N'fxDb2'

It worked for me.. Thanks